a new norm on piecewise linear functions
In symplectic geometry, there is a norm/metric defined on (time dependent) Hamiltonian functions $H:M\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ which is quite useful : A sufficient condition for this to make sense is $H_s:M\to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $H_s(p)=H(p,s)$ is compactly supported(call this timewise compactly supported). Then the norm is defined
$$\Vert H \Vert_0:= \int_0^1\left(\max_{p\in M}H_s(p)-\min_{p\in M}H_s(p)\right)\,ds$$
I'm wondering if there is a variant of this when the functions are not compactly supported timewise. I made a guess as follows :
$$\Vert H \Vert_{new}:=\sup_{K\subset M \text{ compact}}\int_0^1\left(\max_{p\in K}H_s(p)-\min_{p\in K}H_s(p)\right)\,ds$$
Now this defines a norm, but I don't know if this is any kind of standard object, with maybe even any good properties(it might just be $\infty$ for unbounded stuff). So I was wondering if there is any known improvements of this which in some sense refines the first norm I mentioned above. Another option I found is the bounded mean oscillation (BMO) norm, but it is defined slightly differently and it doesn't seem to be related to $\Vert-\Vert_0$ although it seems to be defined on functions which are only locally integrable, which certainly seems to me a bigger space than timewise compactly supported. My real interest is in piecewise smooth/linear functions which are more general than above, but clearly the only property we need is the timewise compactly supported one, once that is ensured, we will be able to basically allow any integrable function. So let me phrase my question best I can -

Question : Is there a norm on functions $H: M\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$(not necessarily smooth) where $M$ is a smooth manifold, which for timewise compactly supported Hamiltonians reduce to $\Vert-\Vert_0$? Specifically, I want this to be defined for piecewise linear/smooth functions. Consider an example, $H:\mathbb{R}^2\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ which is defined as $$H(x,y;t)=\max(x,y,0)$$ $H_t$ is unbounded for every $t$ and this is not smooth, but I can of course approximate it smoothly, but I think $\Vert H\Vert_{new}=+\infty$. So I would like a norm which would potentially assign some meaningful value to this function, but restricted to timewise compactly supported ones, it should give the same value as before.

Please suggest any references or ideas regarding this, I'm fairly comfortable with differential geometry and real analysis and integration theory. Thanks in advance!
